# Rails migration -- not appearing on show.html.erb

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, migration

I had a model named b_page I wanted to create another column , so I ran a migration:

```
rails g migration add_status_to_b_page status:string
```

so migration was successful. Users should be able to update their status     so I put this on the **_form.html.erb**:

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :status %><br>
<%= f.text_field :status %>
</div>
```

was successful but then i added it to the show.html.erb

```
<%= @b_page.status %>
```

but everytime i make a new b_page or edit the current one I dont see it on show.html.erb

Comment: If you open rails console and print a record that you know will have a `b_page` is the value populated?  It's possible that you're `show`ing a record that didn't have a status assigned.  Also, make sure that attribute is whitelisted in your controller.

Comment: You'll need to post more code for us to help you. Also, you tagged with ruby-on-rails-3 is this correct? My answer is for vanilla rails-4 .

Comment: Did you run the migration (e.g. `rake db:migrate`), or only create it?

Comment: yes I ran  bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development

Comment: sorry its rails 4 here is my github repository: https://github.com/Hisaan-Anjum/friends

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your code I guess you have to whitelist the new parameter (status) in your BPageController (at the very bottom, in something like `def bh_pages_params`).

You can check the logs whether the parameter that comes into your controller (via the form) actually arrives at the data (ActiveRecord Model), this whitelisting approach (called `Strong Parameters`) is in place to safe guard your data.

Comment: thx I fixed my problem I forgot to add status in                                                   params.require(:b_page).permit(:Bpage_name, :banner_img, :profile_img, :status)   in my controller

Comment: Great! Then please "close" the question, e.g. by providing and accepting your own answer or editing/accepting mine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

thx I fixed my problem I forgot to add status in

```
params.require(:b_page).permit(:Bpage_name, :banner_img, :profile_img, :status) in my controller
```